# JavaScript - If checkbox is disabled, add class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with the syntax (or maybe with the selectors) on my code. See the [demo](http://jsbin.com/novumofuke/edit?output).

I tried the following code but the results does nothing.

**#1. hasAttribute():**

```
if ($('input[type=checkbox]').hasAttribute("disabled")) {
  $(this).closest('.chkbox').addClass("is-disabled");
}
```

**#2. is():**

```
if ($('input[type=checkbox]').is("[disabled]")) {
  $(this).closest('.chkbox').addClass("is-disabled");
}
// ------------------------------------------------
if ($('input[type=checkbox]').is(":disabled")) {
  $(this).closest('.chkbox').addClass("is-disabled");
}
```

**#3. prop():**

```
if ($('input[type=checkbox]').prop("disabled", true)) {
  $(this).closest('.chkbox').addClass("is-disabled");
}
```

So then I think the problem is on the line:

```
$(this).closest('.chkbox').addClass("is-disabled");
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected result? The demo seems a bit different than the code you supplied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `$(this)` without declaring anything. Thats the reason it's not working. It works in the second example because of the `.change()` function gives the context of the 'thing' (this) that is changing.

This code should work as you desire.

```
$(function() {

  // Grab all inputs with the type checkbox.
  var input = $('input[type=checkbox]')

  // Check for each of the input fields (i, el stands for index, element)
  input.each(function(i, el) {
    // Does it have the attribute disabled?
    if(el.hasAttribute('disabled')) {
      // Add the class 'is-disabled'
      $(el).closest('.chkbox').addClass('is-disabled')
    }
  })

  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest('.chkbox').addClass("is-checked");
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.chkbox').removeClass("is-checked");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: So how can I run the command with the if statement? Or is there other method for this?

Comment: I see why this isn't working. I'm adding the class to the `.chkbox` but your code is adding the class to the field itself. Am I right?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot to include the `.closest()` inside of it!

Comment: `$(el).closest('.chkbox').addClass('is-disabled')` this gives me a red box.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :disabled selector

[see here](https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/)